# Json data is not appending in Meteor template using the each

Tags: javascript, json, templates, meteor, append

I'm trying to get my json data to append in template. There will be several objects so in my template I'm using `{{#each products}}`. Json data seems to appear in console, but nothing happens with data in template.

Here is my js:

```
 if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.product_items.products = function () {
    Meteor.call('getProducts', function(error, result){
      var products = JSON.parse(result.content).products;
      console.log(products);
    }) 
  }
}


if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    Meteor.methods({
      getProducts: function(){
        return HTTP.call("GET", "https://api.url.com/products",
          {params: {access_token: "***"}});
      }
    });
  })}
```

My view:

```
<body>
  {{> product_items}}
</body>

  <template name="product_items">
   {{#each products}}
   <div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="{{preview_url}}"  class="img-thumbnail">
    <h4>{{name}}</h4>
    <p>{{description}}</p>
    <p>
      <a href="{{short_url}}">More</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  {{/each }}

</template>
```

The `console.log(products);` gives me the right data:

```
[Object, Object]
  0: Object
    description: "<p>it's what you need</p>"
    name: "wow product"
    preview_url: "erl.jpg"
    webhook: null
    __proto__: Object
  1: Object
    description: "<p>okok</p>"
    name: "wow nemr"
    preview_url: "surl.jpg"
    webhook: null
    __proto__: Object
  length: 2
  __proto__: Array[0]
```

but it's not appearing in the template. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *return* your value from `Template.product_items.products` function. Of course, this is not directly possible when you're using a method, as methods are asynchronous on the client. You need to take advantage of helper's reactiveness.

Example:

```
var products = null;
var productsDep = new Tracker.Dependency();

Template.product_items.rendered = function() {
  products = null;
  Meteor.call('getProducts', function(error, result) {
    products = JSON.parse(result.content).products;
    productsDep.changed();
  });
};

Template.product_items.helpers({
  products: function() {
    produtsDep.depend();
    return products;
  },
});
```

Comment: `Template.product_items.products = ...` is deprecated. Use `Template.product_items.helpers(...)` instead.

Comment: @nilsi of course. I updated the answer (it was pretty old, you see). `Deps` is `Tracker` now as well.